# Laravel Configure Route with custom Key

Tags: laravel

I want to use this url format :

https://example.com/common-parts-city-slug

I did this :

```
Route::get('common-parts-{city}', 'SeoController@commonPartsCity');
```

It works if if i use the City ID : https://example.com/common-parts-1

But i want to use the slug. So i did :

```
Route::get('common-parts-{city:slug}', 'SeoController@commonPartsCity');
```

And doesn't work with any slug : https://example.com/common-parts-slug-test (error 404)

And my Controller Function

```
public function commonPartsCity(City $city)
    {
        return view('seo.commonpartscity');
    }
```

How i can make it works ?

Thanks

Comment: What does your controller method injection look like? Are you trying to bind it directly to a model? And have you set your models getRouteKey() method?

Comment: Do you have a City with a slug of "slug-test"? Have you tried using `{city:slug}`?

Comment: What is your model name? Is it `City` or is it `Seo`? Also, do you have a `slug` column in your model migration? Is the slug property set for the model your are trying to retrieve?

Comment: @kerbholz i have a city with the slug "slug-test". It's why i don't undestand it doesnt work.

Comment: @Azeame i add the controller method in my initial post.
I don't want to use the getRouteKey() because i don't want to force the call of the slug for all. I just want it on this case. Do you think its possible ?

Comment: @LobsterBaz I use SeoController because i'm gonna use different kind of route just for SEO. I have a slug columns and a city with the slug-test value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was my version of Laravel. I was in 6.x and to use something like {city:slug} you need to upgrade in 7.X